# Corrupted data in std::vector - presumably by wrong assignment

Tags: boost, c++11, stdvector

I'm assigning value to a `uint8_t` inside a vector inside a `boost::tuple` pointer inside a vector. The assignment itself seems to work well but the data seems to be freed immediately after allocation as it tends to get overwritten by other data.

I was thinking `packet* a = new packet;` should allocate a new `packet` and the following `.push_back(a)` should copy the pointer and refer to the same value - obviously I am wrong.
I hope someone sees my mistake; would be grateful for any help.

```
typedef boost::tuple<uint8_t, uint16_t, std::vector<uint8_t> > packet;

static void assignValueToMember(uint8_t& member){
    member = 1;
}
static void assignValueToMember(uint16_t& member){
    member = 2;
}

static void assignValueToMember(std::vector<uint8_t> member){
    int maxIndex = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++){
        uint8_t a;
        assignValueToMember(a);
        member.push_back(a);
    }
}

static void assignValueToMember(std::vector<packet*>& member){

    int maxIndex = 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++){
        packet* a = new packet;
        assignValueToMember(boost::get<0>(*a));
        assignValueToMember(boost::get<1>(*a));
        assignValueToMember(boost::get<2>(*a));

        member.push_back(a);
    }
}

void Base::test(){
    std::vector<packet*> a;
    assignValueToMember(a);

    packet* b = a.front();
    std::vector<unsigned char> c = boost::get<2>(*b);

    std::cout << c.front(); 
}
```

Comment: The vector version of assignValueToMember doesn't take the vector by reference.

Comment: `std::vector<packet*>` would be better as `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<packet>>`.

Comment: std::vector<packet*> would be even better as std::vector<packet> (or, if the packets really cannot be moved in memory for some reason, std::deque<packet>).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static void assignValueToMember(std::vector<uint8_t> member)` you are passing a copy of this vector instead of a reference.

Comment: thank you very much... I did not see that, even while cutting my code for this example. thanks.